# Rails datatables duplicate controls

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, datatables, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using datatables with rails 5.2. Everything works but when I click back it loads the table but puts two sets of controls on the page.

I'm assuming it is something to do with tubolinks but I haven't been able to figure out how to stop it.

datatables.js

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('.datatables-demo').dataTable();
});
```

Table tag:

```
<table class="datatables-demo table table-striped table-bordered" data-turbolinks="false">
```

Any thoughts or suggestions on what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to destroy the datatable when `turbolinks:before-cache`

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:before-cache', function() {
 $('.datatables-demo').datatable().clear().destroy();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Where should I run/place that? In the same datatables.js file? put it before the original one or just replace it? It didn't seem to work so far with what I tried.

Comment: Actually I need to capitalize Datatables. So now the clear() and destroy() seem to be working. It does not render duplicate values, however it does not load the data again. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: are you using `DataTable()` ?